# Using Putty to connect to a Cisco 4010 via built in usb port results in error 1450. Using windows 10 build 19044

Tags: terminal, console, usb, putty, cisco

I'm attempting to connect to a Cisco 4010 network switch via it's built in usb port (which internally is a usb to rs232 adapter wired to the back of the console port).

I have installed the Cisco usb console drivers version 3.1

When I plug into the usb port, the little green LED that indicates that the console port has switched to usb does not light up.

When I run putty, and attempt to connect via serial connection to COM16 (the usb to rs232 in the cisco switch) I get:
Unable to open connection to COM16
Opening '\.\COM16': Error 1450: Insufficient System resources exist to complete the requested service.

I have tried reinstalling the drivers to no effect.

I have 3 identical switches, which give me identical behaviour, all 3 new out of the box with no programming.

Changing the Baud rate makes no difference, not that I'm expecting it to as the issue seems to be COM16 doesn't exist or similar

[Putty Settings and Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VHFN.png)

Comment: DId you set in configuration the parameters about the serial connection?

Comment: @RomeoNinov the configuration in putty? yes I set Parity to None and Flow Control to None, 8 data bits and 1 stop bit as per the Cisco manual. The speed(baud) I have tried a variety of speeds, but specifically 115200 and 9600.

Comment: I talk about this: https://pbxbook.com/voip/sputty.html ANd the speed must be 9600

Comment: This does not seem like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

With the help of a colleague, we narrowed the issue down to windows using a default usb to rs232 driver rather than the cisco one I had installed. The big clue came when I tried using putty inside a VM and it worked, while on the host OS I was still getting error 1450.

We had to compeletely uninstall all drivers, reboot, reinstall drivers manually, reboot, then attempt the usb connection again.

The last comment here describes it:
https://community.cisco.com/t5/cisco-software-discussions/usb-console-cable/td-p/3952600

I will copy the solution across to here, for easier search of the solution for the next person who has the same issue.

For WIn10 , install the setup(x64).exe from the Cisco_usbconsole_driver_3_1.zip.

Check that the Cisco Serial (Comx) is using the correct driver provider which should be Cisco.  Don't use the Cypress driver.

[Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rng9R.png)

To update the driver,

1. If you installed it already and having issues, uninstall it using the setup(x64),exe then reboot PC.

[Uninstall Cisco Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lu5L.png)

2. First, disconnect the blue Cisco USB console cable. Reinstall the Cisco USB console drive using setup(x64).exe from the Windows_64 folder which was extracted from file Cisco_usbconsole_driver_3_1.zip.
3. Reboot PC
4. Open device manager to observe the driver installation.  Check that you see "Cisco USB to Serial Adapter".  If you don't see it repeat the above steps.
5. if you see above "Cisco USB to Serial Adapter". then

[Update Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDwZc.png)
Click UPDATE DRIVER, then Browse my computer for driver software.

6. Choose " Let me pick from a list of available driers on my Computer."  Select "Cisco Serial".

[Pick driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1aw.png)

7. Finally,. connect to the COM port x indicated in the Device Manager,  Ports (COM & LPT) , Cisco Serial (COMx)